# iOS: interacting with other applications

Tags: iphone, ssh, vpn

I want to write an iPad app that provides a secured ([SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell)) tunnel for other apps to communicate over. This means my app has to stay alive in the background while that other app is working. I already found [this Apple guide](http://tinyurl.com/crhj477), and I understand not all applications are allowed to do such things. What if I would pretend to be a [VoIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP) application?

I think this comes closest to what I have in mind. Any better ideas? Any ideas if this could prevent approval by Apple? Are there any similar applications already other than Apple's VPN solution?

Comment: How do you plan to implement the communication between your app and the other apps?

Loopback socket connection or exploiting the url scheme handlers?

Answer (score 1):

It'll almost certainly be rejected for masquerading as a VoIP app. It may be rejected simply for trying to communicate with other apps.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but thank you. In the meantime, I found this, which might be intersting for others, too: http://blog.michael.kuron-germany.de/2010/09/ios-4-1-undocumented-vpn-api-used-by-cisco-anyconnect/